# Joining two different tile

Tags: flooring, tile

We recently had wood-look tiles placed in our living room.  There were already some retro-looking tile in front of the fireplace that we liked and complimented the wood-look tile that was going in.  Is there something that can be placed to join the two different tiles, kind of like a bullnose, but needs to be narrow and has a finished edge?  There is a slight height difference between the 2 tiles (<1/4").

Comment: ...a grout line. Or a strip of a third type of tile and TWO grout lines.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Not raised? What are the relative heights of the tile surfaces?

Comment: I should have been more clearer in my above question.  There is a slight height difference between the tile around the fireplace and the floor tile.  I need something narrow, but with a finished side that you could place around the fireplace tile.

Comment: Please update your question with that information for future readers.

Comment: And which tile is higher? How much?

Comment: The tile around the fireplace is slightly higher than the tile on the floor; less than 1/4"

Answer (score 2):

[Extruded tile edging](http://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Profiles/For-Floors/Same-height-Transitions/Schluter%C2%AE-SCHIENE/p/SCHIENE) is typically installed underneath the tile before it's laid. If your existing tile is at a higher level, this probably won't work as you'll want the outer face of the edging oriented toward the lower tile. It is possible that the hem on the inner face will be tall enough to do the job, however.

[image]

Another option would be a [beveled marble transition strip](http://www.tiling-treasures.com/marble-thresholds.html) (threshold). By placing the bevel toward the lower tile, you'd have a nice finished elevation change.